# Is it possible to infer type parameters from what return values are assigned to?

Tags: go, generics, type-inference

Suppose I wrote two functions like this:

```golang
func ToInterfaceSlice[T any](s []T) []interface{} {
    res := make([]interface{}, len(s))
    for i, v := range s {
        res[i] = v
    }
    return res
}

func FromInterfaceSlice[T any](s []interface{}) (res []T, err error) {
    res = make([]T, len(s))
    for i, v := range s {
        vt, ok := v.(T)
        if !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("%v (type=%T) doesn't fit the target type %T", v, v, res)
        }
        res[i] = vt
    }
    return
}
```

When I parse type from the input parameters, I can simply use

```golang
    var m = []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(ToInterfaceSlice(m))
```

The compiler knows the `T` is `int`.

However when I try passing type from the return variables

```golang
    var m []int
    m, _ = FromInterfaceSlice([]interface{}{1, 2, 3})
    fmt.Println(m)
```

The compiler gives error:

> .\scratch.go:29:27: cannot infer T

I must explicitly pass the type in the function call:

```golang
    var m []int
    m, _ = FromInterfaceSlice[int]([]interface{}{1, 2, 3})
    fmt.Println(m)
```

Is there anything hard to infer type parameters from return type when the receiver vars are not interface? Or just not implemented, even not to implement on purpose?

Update #1 after the comment

I do know `a, b := GenericFunc()` cannot refer the type of returned value. Currently Go does have "it depends" case whether requires the explicit instantiation or not from the user input.

```golang
type Set[T comparable] map[T]struct{}

func NewSet[T comparable](eles ...T) Set[T] {
    s := make(Set[T])
    for _, ele := range eles {
        s[ele] = struct{}{}
    }
    return s
}
```

It's okay to use both `t := NewSet(1, 2, 3)` and `t := NewSet[string]()`, but not `var t NewSet[float64] = NewSet()` now because of this

Comment: This is not yet implemented, there is a issue/proposal for this feature https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50285

Comment: What do you expect on such case: `a, b, c := FunctionXXX(…)` ?

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj Should be a compilation error that cannot infer the type of variable `a`.  Go does have the chance these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current rules for type inference are [explicit](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_inference). How the return values are used is not taken into account:

> Type inference is based on
>
> - a type parameter list
> - a substitution map M initialized with the known type arguments, if any
> - a (possibly empty) list of ordinary function arguments (in case of a function call only)

As of Go 1.18 might simply rewrite your function to accept an argument of the required type; this has also the benefit of not hiding allocations inside the function body:

```
func FromInterfaceSlice[T any](s []interface{}, dst []T) error {
    if len(s) != len(dst) {
        return errors.New("lengths don't match")
    }
    for i, v := range s {
        vt, ok := v.(T)
        if !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("%v (type=%T) doesn't fit the target type %T", v, v, res)
        }
        dst[i] = vt
    }
    return nil
}
```

And pass in a destination slice with the required length:

```
func main() {
    src := []interface{}{1, 2, 3}
    m := make([]int, len(src))
    _ = FromInterfaceSlice(src, m)
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

If you can't or don't want to determine the slice's length beforehand, you are left with explicit instantiation:

```
var m []int
m, _ = FromInterfaceSlice[int]([]interface{}{1, 2, 3})
//                        ^^^ explicit type argument
```

---

Also the type parameters are still not inferrable with `:=` shorthand declaration:

```
// what is m???
m, err := FromInterfaceSlice([]interface{}{1, 2, 3})
```

Comment: Thanks. Till now explicit instantiation seems to be the easiest way for the case.